# Using a function that is inside a class

Tags: c++, class, function, call

I have a class that contains a function right before the contstructor, that itself is empty, and that's all, so my class contains the function only and some not so important elements.

How can I call the function from that to work, but only when I want? `ClassName ObjectName` and then `ObjectName.FunctionName` doesn't work.

This is the content of the header file belongs to the class (Cellstruct.h):

```
typedef struct tiles
{
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
}tiles;

const tiles BASE = {0,0,0};
const tiles TEST_ALIVE = {255,0,0};
const tiles CONWAY_ALIVE = {0,255,0};
const tiles CONWAY_DEAD = {0,50,0};

class Cellstruct
{
public:
    Cellstruct(void);
    virtual ~Cellstruct(void);
};
```

This is the content of the cpp file belongs to the class (Cellstruct.cpp):

```
#include "Cellstruct.h"

bool equality(tiles* a, const tiles* b) 
{
    if (a->red == b->red && a->green == b->green && a->blue == b->blue)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void Automaton(tiles arra[fullwidth][fullheight], tiles arrb[fullwidth][fullheight])
{

//*this is way too long so I cut it, I think it doesn't really matter*

}

Cellstruct::Cellstruct(void)
{
}

Cellstruct::~Cellstruct(void)
{
}
```

Comment: It is fine. thanks for updating the post.

Comment: can you show us how do you call function and what's the error?

Comment: `ObjectName.FunctionName` doing this means `FunctionName` is a member function of your class. If it is not, you simply can't do this way.

Comment: I do `ObjectName.FunctionName` but I get that `'Automaton' : is not a member of 'Cellstruct'` Is the class wrong maybe?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. The compiler told you the error already. What did you try to do exactly?

Comment: I would have those parameters be references, not pointers, and do `return a.red == b.red && a.green == b.green && a.blue == b.blue;`

Comment: I did it, but everything is the same.

Comment: @taocp I tried to call the function of the call within another function the main cpp file.

Comment: Automaton is not a member of the Cellstruct class. If you want it to be a member then the function must be defined like this: void Cellstruct::Automaton(...)

Comment: In that case, **the error message appears in the class cpp file where the function is!** What the hell?

Comment: I don't see any class here

Comment: @kotlomoy Maybe I didn't explain it well, sorry. Obviously, when we create a new class, we get a header file and a cpp file with the name of the class. It was the content of the cpp file. Now I added the content of the header file too. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: "I have a class that contains a function" - I don't see any functions in your class

Comment: @kotlomoy void Automaton(blabla) is the function but I didn't want to put its content heres, because a) it's very long b) as I thought, it doesn't matter, because that didn't made the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `ObjectName.FunctionName` are you referring to your `void Automaton` function?

If so, it doesn't appear to be a part of your Cellstruct class.

your class should contain a prototype for `void Automaton`

In your header, add the prototype:

```
class Cellstruct
{
public:
    Cellstruct(void);
    virtual ~Cellstruct(void);

    void Automaton(tiles arra[fullwidth][fullheight], tiles arrb[fullwidth][fullheight]); //Add this
};
```

And then in your source file, define the function as part of your class.

```
void Cellstruct::Automaton(tiles arra[fullwidth][fullheight], tiles arrb[fullwidth][fullheight])
{
    //*this is way too long so I cut it, I think it doesn't really matter*
}
```